# Limit recursion depth in thrift

Tags: recursion, thrift

I am trying to limit recursion depth of a struct in Thrift.

1) Is it safe to use recursion in thrift?
2) can i limit the depth of recursion in thrift or should i manually validate this in the code?

Using below thrift definition, i am able to access children recursively in the code.

```
Struct A {
1: optional String name;
.
.
10: optional list<A> children;
}
```

Actual: A.children[0].children[0]...

Expected: A.children[0] ---> if the limit is 1

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin limit of 64 levels of nested elements